# Cannot save a file in R. Permissions denied

Tags: r

> saveRDS(seqtab, "C:/Users/Bioinfo/Desktop/Dada2")
>   Error in gzfile(file, mode) : cannot open the connection
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In gzfile(file, mode) :
>     cannot open compressed file 'C:/Users/Bioinfo/Desktop/Dada2', probable reason 'Permission denied'

In a R package called DADA2, I got the following error when I tried to save the sequence table created. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Are you sure you have permissions to write to that folder? The error message clearly says "Permission denied."

Comment: If you had already saved that file and it was open in another application or window, you might get that response.

Comment: There are several reasons for this. It's probably not specific to R. You may not have write permissions in the directory, or the file could be open already.

Comment: It cannot be open already because it was created just then by the algorithm DADA2. I am a biotech student and I am pretty new to coding. I don't have any idea on how can I give write permissions to that folder? I have tried a bunch of other folders too including the desktop too. But nothing worked. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the result of `dir.exists("C:/Users/Bioinfo/Desktop/")`?

Comment: Its TRUE. And I have checked the permissions and it says "Allow Everything" dont know what can the problem be.